# How should the DAO design strategy be for update operation ?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am myself surprised that this question never occurred to me before but this time i am bothered since i am creating my own application.

I have a TaskDetail class that has 30 fields. while updating there could be only a small part of TaskDetail that may be updated like just the "endDate" of the task. We can use two strategies to update this field.

- APPROACH 1 : Update entire object with all the 30 fields and let the rest fields be overwritten in the database with the same value expect the changed field which will be updated with new value.
  OR
- APPROACH 2 : Update just the field that has been changed. In this case we would treat Employee as a DTO and just populate the "endDate" field with new value since it is the only field that needs to be changed.

Both the approaches seem to have its pros and cons

APPROACH 1 : (PROS) - Its a cleaner approach.
             (CONS) - We are unnecessarily over-writing 29 additional field for the sake of one field.

APPROACH 2 : (PROS) - We are just updating the fields that are modified
             (CONS) - Makes the DAO dirty looking because we would need 30 null checks to identify which of field have to be updated.

This problem is making me a little uncomfortable.

Which of this approach is an accepted one or there is a third approach? I am not very much in favor of using hibernate although prefer Spring JDBC template.

Comment: Why won't you use hibernate? This exact same problem is what hibernate helps you avoid. It'll internally do the checks itself and update only the fields which have been changed, in the DB and not bother with the others. Is using hibernate not feasible or you just don't like hibernate?

Comment: why not having in your DAO interface a method updateField(long recordid, String newValue)  ?

Comment: If you go the Hibernate route, you have to enable dynamicUpdate to get approach 2 because Hibernate updates all fields by default (which is a surprise to most people).

Comment: I do feel that hibernate is good in this scenario but for some reasons i dont like hibernate much a) Requires DB to be highly normalized. With hibernate based DAO, you have to design the DB to suit the DAO rather that writing DAO to suit DB. b) Hibernate maintains its own session of objects which is like messing with custom session management strategies like i wish to an external session management eg. terracota/coherence. There is no point terracota and hibernate both maintain the session for same objects. c)oracle,MySQL have many powerful features that are not easily used with hibernate.

Comment: @Leo - Making DAO's granular to field level wont be a good idea, that's like heading yourself to a maintenance havoc every time new fields added.

Comment: I know we got to use one one the above approaches and be contented with pros as well as cons. But i wish to know what is the generally accepted one ? Which approach the majority of us would take up in case we are to use Spring JDBC template?

Answer (score 1):

Just going by gist of information - Approach 1 clearly is an performance overhead as you will be updating all 29 fields every time for each update. You can have more update operations based on the fields you update but it would be more based on your usecase. I would be more worried about performance, maintainability and atomicity when compared to how DAO looks as long as its not complexly written.

Comment: I am not against what you are saying but i have personally witnessed how excessive null checks create a maintenance issues and also bad results if you forget to put one. unrequired fields get updated to null.

Comment: I am not sure if I sounded clear..I am saying you should not go by approach 1 if you have one of two files to be updated.